# What is the difference between "and" and "&&" in c++

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

Recently I found a code where is used the keyword `and` which working like `&&`. So are they both the same or is there any specific condition to use it?

Comment: `and` is an alternative name for `&&`.

Comment: You can even write atrocity like `void foo(std::string and s)` :-/

Comment: @Jarod42     Believe it or not, I once caught a case like that in a formal code review.  I still shudder.     Another time I had someone complaining that the compiler was emitting an error to the effect that `X::operator&&(const X &) const` could not be overloaded for some class `X` - it turned out he had attempted to provide both `X::operator&&(const X &) const` and `X::operator and(const X &) const` - believing they were different.

Comment: @Peter: Epitomises the misunderstanding that `&&` and `and` are not equiavlent operators but are equivalent *tokens*. I decided to answer for that reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ standard permits the *token* `&&` to be used interchangeably with the token `and`.

Not all compilers implement this correctly (some don't bother at all; others require the inclusion of a special header). As such, code using `and` can be considered idiosyncratic.

The fact that the equivalence is at the token, rather than the *operator*, level means that since C++11 (where the language acquired the rvalue reference notation), you can arrange things (without recourse to the preprocessor) such that the statement

```
int and _int(string and vector);
```

is a valid function prototype. (It's eqivalent to `int&& _int(string&& vector)`.)

Comment: Even before c++11, you could have had fun with bitand.

Comment: A number of compilers that are both C and C++ compilers (e.g. with different switches) have a number of similar anomalies.    The "special header" you refer to, in several such cases, is the C header `<iso646.h>` which, from memory, was introduced in about 1995 as an amendment (not a full release) of the C standard - and defines `and`, etc using macros.      (`<iso646.h>` typically gives undefined behaviour in C++, since it uses the preprocessor to `#define` C++ language keywords, but some C++ implementations actually require it if you want the alternative tokens).

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/and), they're the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

No difference. `and` is just an alternative name for `&&`.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/and.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing different in `and` and `&&`

> The and operator is an alternative representation of the && operator (binary or logical AND).

you can see the complete article here -

> http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/And

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between "and" and "&&" in c++

The main difference is that `and` doesn't use the character &.

Otherwise, there is no difference.

> is there any specific condition to use it?

Along with other alternative tokens such as the digraphs, it exists in order to allow writing programs on exotic systems with character encoding (such as BCD or ISO 646) that don't have the special symbols such as &.

Unless you're writing on such system where it's necessary to use alternative tokens, you conventionally shouldn't be using them.

Answer (score 0):

They and operator si they name of the &&

Answer (score -1):

The `and` operator is an alternate to the `&&` operator.